# Explaining The Different Order of Stability for singlet and triplet carbenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

Consider the following singlet carbenes:

$\ce{CH2}$ , $\ce{CF2}$, $\ce{CCl2}$

The order of stability expected considering back bonding is;

$\ce{CH2}$ < $\ce{CCl2}$ < $\ce{CF2}$

However the correct order is:

$\ce{CCl2}$ < $\ce{CH2}$ < $\ce{CF2}$

Can someone explain why dichlorocarbene(singlet) should be less stable than $\ce{CH2}$ even when back-bonding is present in $\ce{CCl2}$ (though it may not be strong).

Also, if we consider the stability order for triplet carbenes, it turns out that the order is just reversed. I assume that back-bonding doesn't work here due to non availability of empty p orbitals. But, if this is so, then what  factor(s) determines their stability?

Edit: There seems to be a confusion with the word stability. I would rather put it as in which species is carbon's electron hunger least/most satisfied(i.e. which are least and most electrophilic)

Comment: Stability with regard for what?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン  I'm interested in their relative stability. To put in simple words, their order of reactivity

Comment: Reactivity towards what? Nucleophilic or electrophilic substitution, for example, are two different shoes. Stability and in that regard reactivity are not absolute concepts, you need to specify what baseline you are comparing them to.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I think the OP means relative stability when these species are formed as reaction intermediates.

Comment: @S007 you are implying that and that also does not define a proper baseline. In what reaction would they be formed, are the settings even comparable. There are just too many uncertainties to give a correct answer. These molecules don't even have the same ground state, significantly different geometries, etc. There is no universal and simple answer to this question and it needs more information.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I'm sorry if my question appears uncertain. I dont know if it is the sole criteria for stability, but I wanted the species arranged in order of fulfilment of carbon's electron hunger(or electrophilic nature). Please check that I have now edited the post

Comment: Where did you get the "correct order" from?